# How to show that the circle group T is isomorphic to $\mathbb R/ \mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory

the circle group is the multiplicative group of all complex numbers of absolute value 1. How can i show that this group is isomorphic with $\mathbb R/ \mathbb Z$. Any hints for the right map is great.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274841/show-that-mathbbr-mathbbz-is-isomorphic-to-ei-theta-0-le-theta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** The complex exponent map.

Answer (score 7):

The map $\phi\colon\Bbb R\to T$ given by $\phi(t)=e^{2\pi it}$ is a group morphism. Hence we can apply [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem).