# Intuition about quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition, quotient-group

I am interested in getting a stronger intuition for quotient groups. I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252108/intuition-behind-quotient-groups) related thread on MSE, but these answers do not seem sufficient for me.

The way I look at quotient groups is the following:

If we have a group $G/H$, then we split up the group $G$ in bigger parts, with the same size as $H$. Moreover, $H$ becomes the neutral element of this group.

For example, when we consider the quotient $(\mathbb{R}_0,.)/(\mathbb{R_0}^{+},.)$, it makes sense that this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, since we divide $\mathbb{R_0}$ in 2 bigger parts ($\mathbb{R_°^{+}},-\mathbb{R_°^{+}})$

Another example: $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Here, in the quotient,we have that $3\mathbb{Z}$ will become the neutral element of the quotient group. This means, every time we encounter a multiple of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, we start over again and counting from $0$.

However, I find that my intuition is lacking when considering examples like $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which should be isomorphic to the unit circle in the complex plane.

So, are there other ways to visualise/think about quotient groups?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A stronger intuitioon, I think, is only possible with additional arguments - so see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274841/show-that-mathbbr-mathbbz-is-isomorphic-to-ei-theta-0-le-theta) for your last example.

Comment: Normal subgroups always appear as the kernel of some group morphism. Understanding the group morphism helps you to understand the quotient. Indeed, for the last example the map $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:x\mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ has $\mathbb{Z}$ as it's kernel. Thus the first isomorphism theorem says that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \text{im}(\phi)$. The point is that the first isomorphism theorem is your friend when it comes to quotients. Finding the proper map might be more natural than thinking about the quotient directly.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Well noticed. This question is more about a general intuition though. The last example was just an illustration where intuition could lack.

Comment: http://www.math3ma.com/mathema/2016/10/17/whats-a-quotient-group-really-part-1 this is one of the most intuitive explanations of quotient groups I've seen, check out part 2 as well

Comment: I thought $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\cong S^1$ is obvious, if you include the topology. Anyway, quotient groups are not always easy to visualise. [$\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$ is an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182247/visualizing-quotient-groups-mathbbr-q).

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2-1)$. I always think of what you kill in a quotient and what survives. So here we kill $X^2-1$, thus $X^2=1$. Clearly $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2-1)$ is "larger" than $\mathbb{R}$ since $X^1$ survives. So actually you are adjoining a solution of $X^2-1=0$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Unsurprisingly, the first isomorphism theorem and the map $\phi:\mathbb{R}[X]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}:p(X)\mapsto p(i)$ give that $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2-1)\cong \mathbb{C}$. Off course these are quotient of rings, but the idea is the same. Polynomial rings and quotient are very important to algebraic geomtery.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb{C}$

Comment: I see it as follows: if $N$ is normal in $G$ then $G/N$ is $G$ with the additional rule that "$N={e}$", so that $N$ is forced to be trivial.

Comment: @Mathematician42 : you meant $X^2 +1$. Math_QED: as many have already said on this site, and as M.Van explains, quotienting is a bit like expanding the definition of equality : in $G/N$, you expand it so that for $n\in N$, $n=e$ is in the expansion.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may also want to look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural way to visualize the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1 $, induced from the epimorphism $ p \colon \mathbb{R} \to S^1 $ defined by $ p(t) = e^{2\pi it}$ for $ t \in \mathbb{R} $
with $ \ker p = \mathbb{Z} $, is the following (though which does not work well in general).

[image]